# Возникает ошибка "no matching function for call to" при попытке передать объект шаблонного класса, в конструктор другого класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пишу свой шаблонный класс map, использую для этого бинарное дерево.
Внутри класса map содержится класс node, который является вложенным и выступает как связывающее звено. Вне класса map создан класс pair, когда я пытаюсь передать в конструктор node объект класса pair компилятор выдает ошибку "no matching function for call to". Что мне нужно исправить, чтоб ошибка перестала вылетать?

Вот проблемное место, напротив реализации этих конструкторов выскакивает эта ошибка.
полный код ошибки:( /home/anton/Programming/map/map.h:106: ошибка: no matching function for call to ‘pair, int>::pair()’
 map::node::node(pair container, node* parent)
                                                                 ^)

```
template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> container)
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    parent = nullptr;
    this->container = container;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> container, node* parent)
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    this->parent = parent;
    this->container = container;
}
```

Вот код целиком:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

template<class Key, class Inf>
class pair
{
public:
    pair(Key first, Inf second);
    Key first;
    Key second;
    bool operator == (const pair<Key, Inf>& other);
    bool operator != (const pair<Key, Inf>& other);
    bool operator > (const pair<Key, Inf>& other);
    bool operator < (const pair<Key, Inf>& other);
    bool operator >= (const pair<Key, Inf>& other);
    bool operator <= (const pair<Key, Inf>& other);
};


template<class Key, class Inf>
pair<Key, Inf>::pair(Key first, Inf second)
{
    this->first = first;
    this->second = second;
}

template<class Key, class Inf>
bool pair<Key, Inf>::operator ==(const pair<Key, Inf>& other)
{
    return this->first == other.first;
}

template<class Key, class Inf>
bool pair<Key, Inf>::operator !=(const pair<Key, Inf>& other)
{
    return this->first != other.first;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
bool pair<Key, Inf>::operator >(const pair<Key, Inf>& other)
{
    return this->first > other.first;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
bool pair<Key, Inf>::operator <(const pair<Key, Inf>& other)
{
    return this->first < other.first;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
bool pair<Key, Inf>::operator >=(const pair<Key, Inf>& other)
{
    return this->first >= other.first;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
bool pair<Key, Inf>::operator <=(const pair<Key, Inf>& other)
{
    return this->first <= other.first;
}



template<class Key, class Inf>
class map
{
private:
    struct node
     {
         node* left;
         node* right;
         node* parent;
         pair<Key, Inf> container;
         node(pair<Key, Inf> container);
         node(pair<Key, Inf> container, node* parent);
         ~node();
     };
public:
    map();
    ~map();
    int size();
    void emplace(Key key, Inf inf);
private:
    void push(pair<Key, Inf> *container, node* current);
    int _size;
    node* root;
};

template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> container) //проблемы здесь
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    parent = nullptr;
    this->container = container;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> container, node* parent)//проблема здесь
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    this->parent = parent;
    this->container = container;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::~node()
{
    if (left != nullptr)
        delete left;
    if (right != nullptr)
        delete right;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::map()
{
    _size = 0;
    root = nullptr;
}



template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::~map()
{
    delete root;
}

template<class Key, class Inf>
void map<Key, Inf>::emplace(Key key, Inf inf)
{
    pair<Key, Inf> *temp = new pair<Key, Inf>(key, inf);
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = new node(*temp);
        _size++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (*temp < root->container)
        {
            if (root->left != nullptr)
                push(temp, root->left);
            else
            {
                root->left = new node(*temp, root);
                _size++;
            }
        }
        else if (*temp > root->container)
        {
            if (root->right != nullptr)
                push(temp, root->right);
            else
            {
                root->right = new node(*temp, root);
                _size++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            root->container = *temp;
        }
    }
    delete temp;
}

template<class Key, class Inf>
void map<Key, Inf>::push(pair<Key, Inf> *container, node* current)
{
    if (*container < current->container)
    {
        if (current->left != nullptr)
            push(container, current->left);
        else
        {
            current->left = new node(*container, current);
            _size++;
        }
    }
    else if (*container > current->container)
    {
        if (current->right != nullptr)
            push(container, current->right);
        else
        {
            current->right = new node(*container, current);
            _size++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        current->container = *container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Конструктор `node` пытается вызвать конструктор по умолчанию для `pair`, а такого нет

Comment: @EOF, а почему по умолчанию, а не копирования, к примеру? И мочему такой проблемы нет в других похожих ситуациях? Как это исправить,  там же возникнут проблемы с передачей параметра, или параметр присвоится после отработки конструктора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор `node` пытается вызвать конструктор по умолчанию для `pair`, а такого нет. Конструктор `node` перед тем, как зайти в фигурные скобки, должен вызвать конструкторы для своих членов.
 Есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы.
Вариант 1:
Вы можете вызвать конструктор копирования (который генерируется по умолчанию)

```
template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> cont) : container(cont)
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    parent = nullptr;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> cont, node* parent) : container(cont)
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    this->parent = parent;
}
```

Вариант 2:
Вызывать свой конструктор для `pair` (кстати говоря, в классе `pair`, член `second` наверное должен быть типа `Inf`)

```
template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> cont) : container(cont.first, cont.second)
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    parent = nullptr;
}


template<class Key, class Inf>
map<Key, Inf>::node::node(pair<Key, Inf> cont, node* parent) : container(cont.first, cont.second)
{
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    this->parent = parent;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. К стыду впервые слышу о такой возможности синтаксиса.

Comment: @DenverToha Это список инициализации членов класса. Конструктор класса `node` делает `this->container = container;`. Но ведь это операция присваивания, а не инициализация. Присвоить можно только существующему обьекту. Значит `this->container` нужно сначала создать. И если этого не делаете Вы сами, то это сделает конструктор `node` вызвав конструктор по умолчанию для 'pair'. Попробуйте напишите класс с говорящими конструкторами и поэксперементируйте, ну и google Вам в помощь:)